# Graal SDK works when the application runs but fails in unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, graalvm, polyglot

I'm using Graal SDK in order to "translate" an R script to Java code.

The line is compiled and behaves well when the application runs:

```
Source.newBuilder("R", new File(config.defaultScriptPath)).build()
```

However, once a unit test that executes this line runs, I get an error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No language and polyglot
> implementation was found on the classpath. Make sure the
> truffle-api.jar is on the classpath.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this error?

Comment: How do you run your unit tests? It seems that you do not run them on GraalVM?

Comment: You're right. I downloaded GraalVM and used it as JRE for the unit tests and it worked :-)
Another problem I have is how to run the test from sbt. 
I run "JAVA_HOME=<path to graal vm> sbt test" and I get the error:
The future returned an exception of type: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: If you have other error after some changes, then ask new question or update existing

Answer (score 0):

Solved by ensuring that GraalVM is used by setting JAVA_HOME